# Comparing timestamp results from Postgres in Jest

Tags: node.js, postgresql, testing, jestjs

I'm writing some tests in Jest for an API that's returning results from Postgres via the `pg` library. I post some data (via a `faker`'ed set of values, `template1`), and then test that what I get back is the same, allowing for an `id` value, and `modified` fields. The `template1` data includes an `approved` property (SQL defn: `approved timestamp with time zone`), which is generated like so:

```
{
  approved: faker.date.past(),
  description: faker.lorem.paragraph(),
  groups: faker.lorem.paragraph(),
}
```

This test is something like this:

```
expect(response.body.rows).toStrictEqual([
    {
      ...template1,
      id: 1,
      modified: null,
    },
  ])
```

The issue is that the test is failing because the returned value of `approved` appears to be a string:

```
expect(received).toStrictEqual(expected) // deep equality

- Expected
+ Received

@@ -1,8 +1,8 @@
  Array [
    Object {
-     "approved": 2019-12-19T03:48:20.613Z,
+     "approved": "2019-12-19T03:48:20.613Z",
      "approved_by": "Percy_Hills@yahoo.com",
```

I've tried casting the `template1.approved` value just prior to the comparison to both a date, and to a string. Both approaches fail. What am I doing wrong, and how do I fix the issue?

Comment: `expect(response.body.rows).toStrictEqual([
        {
          ...template1,
          id: 1,
          modified: null,
          approved: new Date(template1.approved).toJSON(),
        },
      ])` was the answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I didn't try hard enough - the answer was to convert the timestamp to JSON:

```
expect(response.body.rows).toStrictEqual([
    {
      ...template1,
      id: 1,
      modified: null,
      approved: new Date(template1.approved).toJSON(), // here
    },
  ])
```

Comment: you saved my day.

Comment: Glad I could help ;-)